# Changing the color of some pixels in an image in Swift

Tags: performance, image, swift, ios, color

My code is working perfectly fine, except for one-thing. The performance is not up-to the mark. What I am trying to achieve is I have an image with a few circles (each circle has a border with different color than circle fill color).  When the user touches any circle, I want to change the border color of the selected circle. That's working fine, but what isn't working up-to expectation is that we have a table in the UI from which the user can select multiple circles, like 6-12 circles at max. In this 2nd scenario, the implementation is taking 3-4 seconds. Below I am sharing the code snippet I am using, if anything wrong found please guide me.

**NOTE:** I have 2 Images: **Front** and **Back**, front image is displayed to the user and upon user's interaction with the front image, the color of the touched point is taken from the back image and if that touched point is any of the circle on the image, then the `replaceColor` method gets called.

```
func replaceColor(sourceColor: [UIColor], withDestColor destColor: UIColor, tolerance: CGFloat) -> UIImage
    {
        // This function expects to get source color(color which is supposed to be replaced)
        // and target color in RGBA color space, hence we expect to get 4 color components: r, g, b, a
        
//        assert(sourceColor.cgColor.numberOfComponents == 4 && destColor.cgColor.numberOfComponents == 4,
//               "Must be RGBA colorspace")
        
        // *** Allocate bitmap in memory with the same width and size as destination image or back image *** //
        
        let backImageBitmap = self.backImage!.cgImage! // Back Image Bitmap
                
        let bitmapByteCountBackImage = backImageBitmap.bytesPerRow * backImageBitmap.height
        
        let rawDataBackImage = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCountBackImage) // A pointer to the memory block where the drawing is to be rendered

        /// *** A graphics context contains drawing parameters and all device-specific information needed to render the paint on a page to a bitmap image *** //
        
        let contextBackImage = CGContext(data: rawDataBackImage,
                                         width: backImageBitmap.width,
                                         height: backImageBitmap.height,
                                         bitsPerComponent: backImageBitmap.bitsPerComponent,
                                         bytesPerRow: backImageBitmap.bytesPerRow,
                                         space: backImageBitmap.colorSpace ?? CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                         bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue)
        

        // Draw bitmap on created context
        
        contextBackImage!.draw(backImageBitmap, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: backImageBitmap.width, height: backImageBitmap.height))

        // Allocate bitmap in memory with the same width and size as source image or front image
        
        let frontImageBitmap = self.frontImage!.cgImage! // Front Image Bitmap

        let bitmapByteCountFrontImage = frontImageBitmap.bytesPerRow * frontImageBitmap.height

        let rawDataFrontImage = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCountFrontImage) // A pointer to the memory block where the drawing is to be rendered

        let contextFrontImage = CGContext(data: rawDataFrontImage,
                                          width: frontImageBitmap.width,
                                          height: frontImageBitmap.height,
                                          bitsPerComponent: frontImageBitmap.bitsPerComponent,
                                          bytesPerRow: frontImageBitmap.bytesPerRow,
                                          space: frontImageBitmap.colorSpace ?? CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                          bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue)

        // Draw bitmap on created context

        contextFrontImage!.draw(frontImageBitmap, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frontImageBitmap.width, height: frontImageBitmap.height))

        // *** Get color components from replacement color *** \\
        
        let destinationColorComponents = destColor.cgColor.components
        let r2 = UInt8(destinationColorComponents![0] * 255)
        let g2 = UInt8(destinationColorComponents![1] * 255)
        let b2 = UInt8(destinationColorComponents![2] * 255)
        let a2 = UInt8(destinationColorComponents![3] * 255)

        // Prepare to iterate over image pixels
        
        var byteIndex = 0

        while byteIndex < bitmapByteCountBackImage
        {
            // Get color of current pixel
            
            let red = CGFloat(rawDataBackImage[byteIndex + 0]) / 255
            let green = CGFloat(rawDataBackImage[byteIndex + 1]) / 255
            let blue = CGFloat(rawDataBackImage[byteIndex + 2]) / 255
            let alpha = CGFloat(rawDataBackImage[byteIndex + 3]) / 255

            let currentColorBackImage = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha);

            // Compare two colors using given tolerance value
            
            if sourceColor.contains(currentColorBackImage)
            {
                // If the're 'similar', then replace pixel color with given target color

                rawDataFrontImage[byteIndex + 0] = r2
                rawDataFrontImage[byteIndex + 1] = g2
                rawDataFrontImage[byteIndex + 2] = b2
                rawDataFrontImage[byteIndex + 3] = a2
            }
            
            byteIndex = byteIndex + 4;
        }

        // Retrieve image from memory context
        
        let imgref = contextFrontImage!.makeImage()
        let result = UIImage(cgImage: imgref!)

        // Clean up a bit
        
        rawDataBackImage.deallocate()
        rawDataFrontImage.deallocate()
        
        return result
    }
```

Comment: This function is taking 3-4 seconds to run? Did you profile your code? Or are you assuming that this is the slow bit? I don’t know Swift, so can’t do a review, but I’m sure you can do the comparison of pixel values without dividing every value by 255, that seems wasteful. Not 3-4 seconds wasteful, though.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - Yep, the division and multiplication by 255 adds a little overhead, but it is inconsequential to the overhead of the `contains` call and the `UIColor` conversion. As you point out, the “Time Profiler” brings the real issues into stark relief.

Comment: @Rob Wow! Now I’m really curious what happens in that `UIColor` constructor. Nice answer BTW.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I had few leaks and performance issues in my code which got resolved by below answer of Rob

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues.

1. The process of converting to and from `UIColor` objects is very expensive.
2. The process of calling [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains) on an `Array` is O(n).

The time profiler will show you this:

[image]

FWIW, I used a points of interest `OSLog`:

```swift
import os.log

private let log = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: .pointsOfInterest)
```

And logged the range:

```swift
@IBAction func didTapProcessButton(_ sender: Any) {
    os_signpost(.begin, log: log, name: #function)
    let final = replaceColor(frontImage: circleImage, backImage: squareImage, sourceColor: [.blue], withDestColor: .green, tolerance: 0.25)
    os_signpost(.end, log: log, name: #function)
    processedImageView.image = final
}
```

Then I could easily zoom into just that interval in my code using the “Points of Interest" tool. And having done that, I can switch to the “Time Profiler” tool, and it shows that 49.3% of the time was spent in `contains` and 24.9% of the time was spent in `UIColor` initializer.

I can also double click on the the `replaceColor` function in the above call tree, it will show this to me in my code (for debug builds, at least). This is another way of seeing the same information shown above:

[image]

So, regarding `UIColor` issue, in [Change color of certain pixels in a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31661519/1271826), I explicitly use `UInt32` representation of the color (and have a `struct` to provide user-friendly interaction with this 32-bit integer). I do this to enjoy efficient integer processing, and avoiding `UIColor`. In that case, processing colors in a 1080×1080 px image takes 0.03 seconds (avoiding the `UIColor` to-and-fro for each pixel).

The bigger issue is that `contains` is very inefficient. If you must use `contains` sort of logic (once you are using `UInt32` representations of your colors), I would suggest using a `Set`, with [O(1) performance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1540013-contains), rather than `Array` (with [O(n) performance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains)).

But even with that `contains` is inefficient approach. (In my example, my array had only one item.) I see an unused `tolerance` parameter, and wonder if you might consider doing this mathematically rather than looking up colors in some collection.

---

Unrelated to your performance issue, you have a very serious memory problem here. The provided code snippet is calculating `bitmapByteCountFrontImage` and `bitmapByteCountBackImage` as width × height, but it should be width × height **× 4**. Your context uses 4 bytes per pixel, so make sure you allocate your buffer accordingly.

Personally, I get out of the business of manually allocating buffers, and let `CGContext` do that for me:

```
let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue

let contextFrontImage = CGContext(data: nil,
                                  width: frontImageBitmap.width,
                                  height: frontImageBitmap.height,
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,                      // eight bits per component, not source image bits per component
                                  bytesPerRow: frontImageBitmap.width * 4,  // explicitly four bytes per pixel, not source image bytes per row
                                  space:  CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),    // explicit color space, not source image color space
                                  bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

guard let dataFrontImage = contextFrontImage?.data else {
    print("unable to get front image buffer")
    return nil
}
let rawDataFrontImage = dataFrontImage.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
```

And, when you do this, it frees you from manually deallocating later (which, when you start passing around images, gets very complicated very quickly).

I would also advise against referencing the source image’s bytes per row, bits per component, and color space. The whole purpose of creating and drawing in this new context and grabbing its buffer, is to get a new, known, and predetermined format, not relying on the original image parameters. This obviates the `assert` logic that you have commented out at the start of your routine, as we no longer care about the format of the original images.

---

For example, here is a rendition that uses 32 bit integers for colors and replaces the `contains` logic with an arithmetic calculation and it processes a 1080×1080 px image on simulator in a release build in 0.01 seconds:

```swift
/// Replace colors in “front” image on the basis of colors within in the “back” image matching a requested color within a certain tolerance.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - frontImage: This is the image that will be used for the basis of the returned image (i.e. where `searchColor` was not found in `backImage`.
///   - backImage: The image in which we're going to look for `searchColor`.
///   - searchColor: The color we are looking for in the backImage.
///   - replacementColor: The color we are going to replace it with if found within the specified `tolerance`.
///   - tolerance: The tolerance (in `UInt8`) to used when looking for `searchColor`. E.g. a `tolerance` of 5 when
/// - Returns: The resulting image.

func replaceColor(frontImage: UIImage, backImage: UIImage, searchColor: UIColor, replacementColor: UIColor, tolerance: UInt8) -> UIImage? {
    guard
        let backImageBitmap = backImage.cgImage,
        let frontImageBitmap = frontImage.cgImage
    else {
        print("replaceColor: Unable to get cgImage")
        return nil
    }

    let searchColorRGB = RGBA32(color: searchColor)
    let (searchColorMin, searchColorMax) = searchColorRGB.colors(tolerance: tolerance)
    let replacementColorRGB = RGBA32(color: replacementColor)

    /// Graphics context parameters

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = RGBA32.bitmapInfo
    let width = backImageBitmap.width
    let height = backImageBitmap.height

    // back image

    let backImageBytesPerRow = width * 4
    let backImagePixelCount = width * height
    let contextBackImage = CGContext(data: nil,
                                     width: width,
                                     height: height,
                                     bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                     bytesPerRow: backImageBytesPerRow,
                                     space: colorspace,
                                     bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

    guard let dataBackImage = contextBackImage?.data else {
        print("replaceColor: Unable to get back image buffer")
        return nil
    }
    let bufferBackImage = dataBackImage.bindMemory(to: RGBA32.self, capacity: width * height)
    contextBackImage!.draw(backImageBitmap, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

    // front image

    let contextFrontImage = CGContext(data: nil,
                                      width: width,
                                      height: height,
                                      bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                      bytesPerRow: width * 4,
                                      space: colorspace,
                                      bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

    guard let dataFrontImage = contextFrontImage?.data else {
        print("replaceColor: Unable to get front image buffer")
        return nil
    }
    let bufferFrontImage = dataFrontImage.bindMemory(to: RGBA32.self, capacity: width * height)
    contextFrontImage!.draw(frontImageBitmap, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

    // Prepare to iterate over image pixels

    for offset in 0..<backImagePixelCount {
        let color = bufferBackImage[offset]

        // Compare two colors using given tolerance value

        if color.between(searchColorMin, searchColorMax) {
            bufferFrontImage[offset] = replacementColorRGB
        }
    }

    // Retrieve image from memory context

    return contextFrontImage?.makeImage().flatMap {
        UIImage(cgImage: $0)
    }
}
```

Where

```swift
struct RGBA32: Equatable {
    private var color: UInt32

    var redComponent: UInt8 {
        return UInt8((color >> 24) & 255)
    }

    var greenComponent: UInt8 {
        return UInt8((color >> 16) & 255)
    }

    var blueComponent: UInt8 {
        return UInt8((color >> 8) & 255)
    }

    var alphaComponent: UInt8 {
        return UInt8((color >> 0) & 255)
    }

    init(red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) {
        let red   = UInt32(red)
        let green = UInt32(green)
        let blue  = UInt32(blue)
        let alpha = UInt32(alpha)
        color = (red << 24) | (green << 16) | (blue << 8) | (alpha << 0)
    }

    init(color: UIColor) {
        var red:   CGFloat = .zero
        var green: CGFloat = .zero
        var blue:  CGFloat = .zero
        var alpha: CGFloat = .zero

        color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        self.color = (UInt32(red * 255) << 24) | (UInt32(green * 255) << 16) | (UInt32(blue * 255) << 8) | (UInt32(alpha * 255) << 0)
    }

    func colors(tolerance: UInt8) -> (RGBA32, RGBA32) {
        let red   = redComponent
        let green = greenComponent
        let blue  = blueComponent
        let alpha = alphaComponent

        let redMin   = red   < tolerance ? 0 : red   - tolerance
        let greenMin = green < tolerance ? 0 : green - tolerance
        let blueMin  = blue  < tolerance ? 0 : blue  - tolerance
        let alphaMin = alpha < tolerance ? 0 : alpha - tolerance

        let redMax   = red   > (255 - tolerance) ? 255 : red   + tolerance
        let greenMax = green > (255 - tolerance) ? 255 : green + tolerance
        let blueMax  = blue  > (255 - tolerance) ? 255 : blue  + tolerance
        let alphaMax = alpha > (255 - tolerance) ? 255 : alpha + tolerance

        return (RGBA32(red: redMin, green: greenMin, blue: blueMin, alpha: alphaMin),
                RGBA32(red: redMax, green: greenMax, blue: blueMax, alpha: alphaMax))
    }

    func between(_ min: RGBA32, _ max: RGBA32) -> Bool {
        return
            redComponent   >= min.redComponent   && redComponent   <= max.redComponent &&
            greenComponent >= min.greenComponent && greenComponent <= max.greenComponent &&
            blueComponent  >= min.blueComponent  && blueComponent  <= max.blueComponent
    }

    static let red     = RGBA32(red: 255, green: 0,   blue: 0,   alpha: 255)
    static let green   = RGBA32(red: 0,   green: 255, blue: 0,   alpha: 255)
    static let blue    = RGBA32(red: 0,   green: 0,   blue: 255, alpha: 255)
    static let white   = RGBA32(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 255)
    static let black   = RGBA32(red: 0,   green: 0,   blue: 0,   alpha: 255)
    static let magenta = RGBA32(red: 255, green: 0,   blue: 255, alpha: 255)
    static let yellow  = RGBA32(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 0,   alpha: 255)
    static let cyan    = RGBA32(red: 0,   green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 255)

    static let bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```swift
let resultImage = replaceColor(frontImage: frontImage, backImage: backImage, searchColor: .blue, replacementColor: .green, tolerance: 5)
```

Resulting in (with the front, back and resulting images, going left to right):

[image]

Clearly, you can implement the `tolerance` logic however you want, but hopefully this illustrates the idea that excising `UIColor` and collection searching can have a dramatic impact on performance.

Comment: thanks a lot for saving my time!! The way you described each and every issue and solution to that was more than amazing. Now my code is working like a charm after I followed your instructions and your code snippet.